# what is the meaning of percent sign expressions in html tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I found some strange sign <%%> in angular2-seed, what is the <% %> used for?

https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/src/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>

  <meta name="description" content="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %>">

  <% if (webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags) { %>
  <!-- Configured Head Tags  -->
  <%= webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags %>
  <% } %>

  <!-- base url -->
  <base href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.baseUrl %>">


</head>

<body>

  <app>
    Loading...
  </app>

 .....

  <% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.isDevServer && htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.HMR !== true) { %>
  <!-- Webpack Dev Server reload -->
  <script src="/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
  <% } %>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's HTML Webpack Plugin
https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin

If you search for HtmlWebpackPlugin against the project, you will get the following js, and it points to the template file, and the template engine helps decode it to html file.

```
   /*
   * Plugin: HtmlWebpackPlugin
   * Description: Simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles.
   * This is especially useful for webpack bundles that include a hash in the filename
   * which changes every compilation.
   *
   * See: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
   */
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'src/index.html',
    title: METADATA.title,
    chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
    metadata: METADATA,
    inject: 'head'
  }),
```

I think this is what you were trying to figure out.

Answer (score 5):

That's usually processed by code in the HTTP server and replaced by dynamically generated strings before the complete page is sent as response to a browser request.

See for example

- https://www.mgtek.com/helpproducer/manual/html/hpconHTMLTemplates.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages